# AT+CMGS Sms Sent But Not Received

Tags: sms, avr, gsm

I seem to be having a strange issue. Using Sim808 modem, I am periodically sending SMS out.

With my AT+CMGS command, I get an OK and that the SMS was sent to the operator, but it never reaches the destination. Using the same SIM card in a phone, I am able to send SMS just fine.

This is my sms command response

```
>AT+CMGS="+919577634145",145

> Keedaaaa
0
0
(16/1/18 10:27:2)
60% 3884mv
4184
24.31C
(16/1/18 10:25:20)
64% 3917mv
4189
24.48C


+CMGS: 186

OK
```

And these are my modem initialization steps

```
[0:1:19] External_sim808 - Connecting to network...

RDY

+CFUN: 1

+CPIN: READY

*PSUTTZ: 2018,1,16,4,54,49,"+22",0

DST: 0

+CIEV: 10,"40445","airtel","AIRTEL", 0, 0
>AT+IPR=9600

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>ATE0

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CLTS?

+CLTS: 1

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CMEE=1

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CMGF=1

OK
uart flag = 0x1

Call Ready

SMS Ready
>AT+CPMS="ME","ME","ME"

+CPMS: 0,50,0,50,0,50

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CMGDA="DEL ALL"

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 28,0

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+COPS=0

OK
uart flag = 0x1
>AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,5

OK
uart flag = 0x1
[0:1:58] External_sim808 - network registration ok
```

Weird thing is, this only seem to happen on some service provider networks. On some others, the SMS go out just fine.

I have checked and ensured that the module has the right SMSC number.

Is there any other setting that I need to do? Or execute any other command to atleast help me in figuring out what could be happening here?